# Why order_by() doesn't work in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-order-by

why not worked `order_by` in `codeigniter`?

```
$this->db->order_by("id", "desc")->query('SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, t.* FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, hotel_submits t');
```

Comment: Does it return an error? I think your mixing the use of Active Records with regular queries.

Comment: @MaartenC89 - The error does not, Just does not work. But there is in this case error: `$this->db->query('SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, t.* FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, hotel_submits t')->order_by("id", "desc");` **error->** `Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_result::order_by() in D:\xampp\htdocs\mehdi\application\controllers\admin\accommodation.php on line 20` **line 20 is same top code**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$query= $this->db->query('SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, t.* FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, hotel_submits t order by id desc');
```